# Why real press Ctrl-C key make input function ignore previous input but SIGINT or raise KeyboardInterrupt do not?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, sigint

Reproducible code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
import os
import signal
try:
    time.sleep(5)
    #raise KeyboardInterrupt or send SIGINT to this program itself
    os.kill(os.getpid(),signal.SIGINT)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("*"+input("e:\n"))
```

Input somethings then just wait timeout for SIGINT or the KeyboardInterrupt exception:

```
$ ./test.py
within timeout
e:
*within timeout
```

Input somethings then immediately press the Ctrl-C cause a block wait for user input and previous inputed content ignored:

```
$ ./test.py
within timeout
^Ce:
after real Ctrl-C
*after real Ctrl-C
```

Why is this difference?
I guess it's somethings relate to ["^C"(End-of-Text character)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Text_character) and the implementation of input function to handle the "^C" control character.
Is my guess correctly?
Also I want to switch those behaviors on demand.

Comment: Are you sure that the code you posted prints `within timeout` and `after real Ctrl-C` text?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank for prompt, I update code to indicate out input and output.

Comment: I suppose it's simply because terminal erases buffer before sending signal (in case of Ctrl+C).